# Delete animation

Tags: animation, linked-data

I got an animation, deleted all the keyframes, no fake user and it is still there.
Went to dope sheet and F-Curve editor, checked the ghost icon, still there are no keyframes.
I got little knowledge of how material or animation data is linked to a user and when it is linked to nothing it will be erased automatically.
The animation seems to be linked to nothing yet it won't be erased.

How do I get rid of it?

Edit: I found out that the animation is saved in the action stash of the armature. Still googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it out... kind of:

The animations were saved as NLA tracks in action stashes and you can delete them in the NLA editor.

I dont really know how much of the above is complete bs, it can be quite confusing, if someone would like to share his expertise and explain the issue correctly please do so.

Comment: Had the same problem and this fixed it, thanks.